# Can you propose any hack for remembering multiplication tables from $13-19$?

Tags: arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

I memorized multiplication tables from $2-12$ when I was in elementary school.

Regarding tables $13-19$:

1. I remember some intermittent elements
2. I find others by *multiplication by recombination*. E.g., I would calculate $14 \times 4 \Rightarrow 7 \times 8 \Rightarrow 56$, etc.

However, I am not satisfied with this as I miss almost half of them. E.g., I don't remember the result of $17 \times 7$, etc.

The following YouTube videos present some hacks:

1. [$17$ times table](https://youtu.be/PV_PAPs4j1w)
2. [$18$ times table](https://youtu.be/2HgQ4BsIwKc)
3. [$19$ times table](https://youtu.be/hxwnd7hAOvs)

However, they aren't homogeneous. I.e., they devised unique techniques for each of the tables.

Can you propose any better hack for remembering multiplication tables from $13-19$?

Comment: Your recombination method extends in the so-called [russian multiplication method](https://mathcurious.com/2019/12/29/the-russian-multiplication-method/)

Comment: My suggestion: don't bother. I don't think it is useful to be able to compute things like $14 \cdot 17$ from memory.  I agree that multiplication tables for smaller numbers up through $12 \cdot 12$ are good to learn by heart, though. Maybe *just* learn the squares $13^2, 14^2, 15^2, 16^2$, and $17^2$ and then use the distributive law to work out other cases when they arise if you want to do this in your head. For instance, I know $14^2 = 196$, so $14 \cdot 17 = 14(14+3) = 14^2 + 14 \cdot 3 = 196 + 42$ (I did $14 \cdot 3$ in my head right now), and that last sum is $190+40+6+2 = 230+8 = 238$.

Comment: @Kcd Well, the standard $(10+a)(10+b)=100+10(a+b)+ab$ is not much longer. The question is rather how to quickly learn to "see" the result without *any* computation and I wish I knew the answer even for the standard $1-9$ range...

Comment: @fedja I don't know how to know such products without computing *something*. In the case of multiplication tables through $9 \times 9$ or $10 \times 10$ or some other cutoff, ultimately this seems like something you just have to practice so you can recall it on demand. Once you know it, there's no need to constantly practice (unlike doing scales on a piano), just like you don't have to relearn how to ride a bike once you develop that skill well the first time. Someone interested in primes might similarly learn to recognize primes up to $100$ by memorizing a list (that doesn't include $57$).

Comment: :-) for [57](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/57_(number))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing new in this answer. It is just a reminder that you *already know* a unified method for the multiplication tables from $13$ to $19$. Since you already have multiplication tables from $3$ to $9$ in your mind, you can use them in a *two-step* approach for multiplication tables from $13$ to $19$.

Here I show the table entries from $17$ to $19$, the other entries can be derived in the same way. We consider
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{r|rrr|r}
\cdot&17&1\color{blue}{8}&19\\
\hline
1&7&8&9&+\ 10\\
2&14&16&18&+\ 20\\\
3&21&24&27&+\ 30\\\
\color{blue}{4}&28&\color{blue}{32}&36&\color{blue}{+\ 40}\\\
5&35&40&45&+\ 50\\\
6&42&48&54&+\ 60\\\
7&49&56&63&+\ 70\\\
8&56&64&72&+\ 80\\\
9&63&72&81&+\ 90\\\
10&70&80&90&+\ 100\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}
where we list in

- the column with $17$ the multiples of $7$
- the column with $18$ the multiples of $8$
- the column with $19$ the multiples of $9$
- the rightmost column contains the corresponding multiple of $10$ which has to be added.

**Example:** $18\cdot 4 = (8+10)\cdot 4 = \color{blue}{(8\cdot 4) + 40} = 72$ according to the blue marked entries in the table.